# iOS6 xib error "loaded the "ViewController" nib but the view outlet was not set.'"

Tags: objective-c, ios, interface-builder, ios6, xib

I have read several other posts on SO about this and all say there is an issue with my view not being set on the File Owner. This makes sense, however my view IS set as well as all of my other connections in the XIB and I keep getting this error.

I tried using the loadView approach instead of viewDidLoad approach and it loaded just fine, however it is a "widget-intensive" app so I'd prefer to use a xib if possible.

It was working earlier, but then I made some massive changes. However as it is just a simple app for fun, I wasn't bothering with source control so I can't go back now.

Any idea how to debug this kind of problem or where to start looking?

Cheers

Comment: Is this the first NIB you are showing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a very specific error message so it should not be too hard to debug.

Make sure you are looking at the correct XIB ->  try deleting the XIB and see if it complains that the file dosnt't exist.

Check the class type of the files owner.  It must match the ViewController you are tying to initiate.  If it doesn't, set it correctly.

Check the view outlet dons't have a yellow warning next to it.  If so delete the outlet and remake it.

Check the line of code you are initing the view controller with.  Check it has the correct class and nib name.

Check that the XIB is included in the target.