# Loading UITableViewCell from xib results in loaded the nib but the view outlet was not set

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, xib

I'm trying to create a UITableViewController that it's UITableViewCell is a xib file. The Xib file is empty (0 controls) all the controls are created programmatically like this

```
- (id) initWithTitle: (NSString*)p_title andImage: (UIImage*)p_image
{
    //adding checkbox & title
    MMCheckbox* myCheckbox = [[MMCheckbox alloc] initWithTitle:p_title andHeight:20];
    myCheckbox.frame = CGRectMake(self.frame.size.width - myCheckbox.frame.size.width -15,20, myCheckbox.frame.size.width, 20);
    myCheckbox.flat = YES;
    myCheckbox.strokeColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    myCheckbox.checkColor = [UIColor magentaColor];
    myCheckbox.uncheckedColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    myCheckbox.tintColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [self addSubview:myCheckbox];

    //adding the image
    UIImageView* imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake (15, 10, 20, 20)];
    [imageView setImage: p_image];

    return self;
}
```

In the xib file I placed a UITableViewCell and set it's class to my class MMCheckboxTableViewCell

[image]

In my tableViewController I'm creating the cell loading it from NIB like so

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)p_tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)p_indexPath
{
//create a UI tableViewCell
    UITableViewCell* cell = [p_tableView
                             dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"comboBoxCell"];
    if(cell == nil)
    {
        UIViewController *temporaryController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MMComboBoxTableCell" bundle:nil];
        // Grab a pointer to the custom cell.
        cell = (MMComboBoxTableCell *)temporaryController.view;
    }
}
```

I've looked at many post with the same question and checked to see I've got every thing right according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13323514/ios6-xib-error-loaded-the-viewcontroller-nib-but-the-view-outlet-was-not-set).

Please let me know what I'm missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was with the way I was loading the XIB.

By changing the following:

```
UIViewController *temporaryController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MMComboBoxTableCell" bundle:nil];
```

to this:

```
MMComboBoxTableCell* temporaryController = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MMComboBoxTableCell" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
```

Problem solved.

Comment: What you're doing here is quite odd. First, if you're making all the controls in code, why use a xib at all? The purpose of using a xib is so you can add those subviews in IB. Second, even if you're using a xib, you wouldn't use a view controller to load it. You should use registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier:, which you can put in viewDidLoad. The xib should just contain a stand alone table view cell not associated with a view controller.